# How to point a registered domain to another server's subdomain?

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, domain, subdomain, web-hosting

I have created a subdomain at my hosting server,

```
e.g. test.myserver.com
```

And recently the site need to go to production, therefore, I have registered a domain for the site:

```
e.g. production.com
```

So, I would like to point the `production.com` to the `test.myserver.com`, in the domain admin panel, there input boxes for two name servers.

The problem is, at hosting server, there are only two name servers record for the main domain:

e.g.

```
myserver.com NS ns222.pointdnshere.net
myserver.com NS ns223.pointdnshere.net
```

but no record for the sub-domain, so , how to point to subdomain instead of the main domain?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What on earth are you talking about? Why don't you just skip the other "subdomain" and set up the new domain normally?

Comment: sorry for confusing , at my hosting server, I have build subdomain for each project, that's why using subdomain

Comment: Just create a standard A or CNAME record.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is create an A record in your DNS that points to the correct IP address.

Comment: Thanks a lot, if I insert insert the nameserver in that domain, will it replace my main server? I would like to keep the myserver.com, but test.myserver.com should replaced by production.com

Comment: I afraid it will be like that: myserver.com is replaced by production.com , and test.production.com is pointing to the test.myserver.com

Comment: Multiple different A records can point to the same IP address simultaneously.

Comment: I really think you need to read up on DNS. This book may be of some use http://www.dummies.com/education/internet-basics/dns-what-it-is-and-what-it-does/  (please excuse the "dummy" reference, I've read a few of this brand of book myself and know they're usually well written)

Comment: I prefer the [TCP/IP Guide](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPIPDomainNameSystemDNS.htm) but it is perhaps a little advanced for this.